# Itext error IllegalArgumentException: Tagging must be set before opening the document

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using itext to fill a template pdf, but I want to add tag to the template pdf and to the elements that I am trying to fill into it.

The first step that I made is trying to insert tag for the element that I am trying to insert into, here my code:

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("myTemplatepath");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);

    PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
    writer.setTagged();   //Make document tagged
```

But when I am using writer.setTagged() I have the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tagging must be set before opening
>   the document

I saw, in this [Topic](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Generating-Tagged-PDF-file-using-PdfStamper-td2151508.html) that the problem is that PdfStamper doesn't support tagging,and the best solution is to create a new PDF and tagged it so my question is :

Since the topic is from 2007, there is any new implementation about this? 
If not, what is the best way to doing so? The template that I have is not so simple and It has editable elements ( that i fill automaticatily).

Comment: Tagging an untagged PDF document is an extremely difficult task that involves human input if you want the document to be properly tagged. We've made progress using AI to detect structure in unstructured documents, but that is not something we are willing to bring into open source. If you want more info about that research project, you'll have to contact the company responsible for iText.

Comment: thank you for the answer, there is any alternative ? Like convert pdf to html and trying to recreate pdf using tag, or something like this ?

Comment: Converting PDF to HTML will create an HTML where content is rendered in a way that the human eye can see structure, but internally the structure of the HTML will be as bad as the structure of an unstructured PDF. I could explain how to make a PDF that is tagged from a technical point of view, but the fines and financial penalties for "faking" accessibility are so high in some countries that I wouldn't do you a favor if I helped you out.

Comment: So the only possible solution is to recreated the pdf with tagged elements, with xml I have the same problem as with html structure?

Comment: The problem is: will your XML have the correct semantics? How can you teach a machine which line is the title of a chapter and which line belongs to a paragraph?.How do you teach a machine to add a meaningful description to an image? How do you teach a machine to recognize and distinguish the different rows and columns of a table? You need some kind of artificial intelligence if you want to automate this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I Imaged the answer but I tried it the same